# error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException unkown error : net :: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in chrome"

Tags: java, selenium

Code is running fine in local but in jenkins I' getting this errror org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException unkown error : net :: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in chrome

Language java

Comment: Please share full trace log

Answer (score 0):

Might be the fact that you are trying to reach url that is only accessible via vpn?
Please share the full error log & more information what you are trying to do.